# Is there a way to download a previous version of Nessus?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I need a verson of Nessus that is compatible with Linux 32-bit. I was told that 5.2.7 would suffice, but I can't find it on the internet, and the only available downloads on the website are of versions 6.x, and they are not compatible with 32-bit anymore. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you want to download an older version of kali, or even backtrack...

Comment: You mean an older version of kali in order to use 64-bit?

Comment: An older version of 32Bit Kali, which should contain nessus 5.

Comment: Try this wget https://support.tenable.com/dl_secure.php?sid=4cgsg7pmof2calkh1tul88sqk5&p=Nessus-5.2.11-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb Did you try an older Kali version?